# Modifying two examples on the same page thinks I'm modifying one

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

I edited one example on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/189/hello-world/722/html-output-from-web-server#t=201607182117321292434), removing some unneeded sections.  when I was done the page helpfully told me only I could see it until it was approved.

I then went to edit an other example on the page but when I went to submit it seemed to give the same description as my first edit, suggesting it thought I was editing the same example, I was not.

I think this is a bug.

Comment: Each edit needs to be approved separately.  Each needs a description, and the only difference between the two is where the link goes.  Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 9):

Think of it less as "I'm editing an example" and more as "I'm editing a topic".

At the core of Documentation is one of the biggest technical deviations from Q&A - edits are more like "commits" to a repository where a topic acts as the repo and examples/topic sections are sort of like individual files in a commit.

When you go to edit another example, what happens is that your submitted proposed change is silently retracted, your new edits are added to it, and it's resubmitted with all of your changes to the topic combined.